# imagecreatefrompng is not working at all

Tags: php, php-gd

I already checked the file with mime type. If it is jpg or gif it is working perfectly with

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpName);
```

and

```
$src = imagecreatefromgif($tmpName);
```

but if the image is **png**
`$src = imagecreatefrompng($tmpName)`;

`src` variable is empty in the **png** case, but in **jpg** and **gif** it is showing it's `resource id`.

would someone tell me what i need to do?

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    unset($_FILES["photo"]["type"]);
    $_FILES["photo"]["type"] = $mime;

    if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

        if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error uploading file <a href='step-1.php'> Try again. </a>";
            $image_check = 0;
            exit;
        } else {

            $image_check = 1;
            $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
            $tmpName = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
            list($width1, $height1, $typeb, $attr) = getimagesize($tmpName);

            //$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

            $size = filesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

             $ext = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];

            if ($ext == 'image/jpeg' || $ext == 'image/jpg') {
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpName);
        } else if ($ext == 'image/gif') {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($tmpName);
        }
            else if(($ext=='image/png')||($ext=='image/x-png'))
         {
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($tmpName);
           }
       $newwidth1 = 624;


        $newheight1 = ($height1 * $newwidth1) / ($width1);
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight1);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth1, $newheight1, $width1, $height1);
        $filename = "resources/images/" . $append . $_FILES['photo']['name'];

         if ($ext == 'image/jpeg' || $ext == 'image/jpg') {
            imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 90);
        } else if ($ext == 'image/gif') {
            imagegif($tmp, $filename, 90);
        }
        else if(($ext=='image/png')||($ext=='image/x-png'))
        {

            imagepng($tmp, $filename, 90);
        }
```

Comment: can u paste your code snippet ??

Comment: In general that function works fine. We'll need something more to go on to help you with your *specific* case.

Comment: Have you specified the header for PNG type image ?

Comment: this code is working perfectly for jpg and gif images but not for png.

Comment: yeah, I tried that header('Content-Type: image/png');
                imagepng($tmp, $filename, 90);but it is not working .

Comment: Have you enabled full error reporting (ie `E_ALL`)? You may find `$src` isn't being set at all. Also, rather than rely on the uploaded `type` property, why not look at `$typeb` and compare it to one of the `IMAGETYPE_*` constants? See [here](https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506#file-imagemanipulator-php-L43) for an example

Answer (score 9):

Write a file

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Browse it, you will see `JPG Support` and `GIF create Support` are `enabled` but  `PNG Support` is `disabled`.

Enable `PNG Support`, it will work.

[image]

Comment: Answer is edited, you have need to enable PNG Support perhaps

Comment: Will you try, else if((strtolower($ext)=='image/png')||(strtolower($ext)=='image/x-png'))

Comment: Another thing, have to check the image you are trying is valid png or not.

Comment: mime type is used to check the image type. I guess this is validate whether the image is png or not.. If I am wrong correct me.

Answer (score 7):

Change from

```
imagepng($tmp, $filename, 90);
```

to

```
imagepng($tmp, $filename);
```

Comment: Note that [`imagepng`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) expects a `quality` value between -1 and 9. I assume this is the reason for the proposed change.