# How to convert PNG img to JPG img in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-6, image-conversion

I need some help on converting PNG files to JPG. I tried [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression) but with no success. Can you help me?

HTML

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="logo" name="logo" / >
<label class="custom-file-label" for="logo"></label>
</div>
```

LARAVEL

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->logo->move(public_path('/dist/img/logo'), $imageName);
$company->logo                      = $imageName;  
$company->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first install this Library .
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

in controller import it,

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

change in your code

```
$image = $request->file('logo');
$imageName = time().'.'."jpg";

Image::make($image)->encode('jpg', 65)
            ->save(public_path('/dist/img/logo' . $imageName));
$company->logo                      = $imageName;  
$company->save();
```

Comment: Thanks! In DB the <filename.jpg> is ok, but the file is not uploaded to the folder I set. Any help?

Comment: in public folder? is your path is absolute?

Comment: for test you can try to save i root public path ('/').
```Image::make($image)->encode('jpg', 65)
            ->save(public_path('/' . $imageName));```

Comment: well, thank you, but I don't know why the image disappears. I think the conversion is ok because the name is stored on DB.

Comment: Thanks. It helped! Hint: The link is broken :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

```
$clientFile = pathinfo($_FILES['logo']['name']);
if($clientFlie['extension'] == 'png'){ 
    $ImageNameWithNewExtensionForClient = $clientFile['filename']."jpg";
 }
```

after you can move **$ImageNameWithNewExtensionForClient** to any path you want.

Answer (score 0):

May be your `JPG Support` is disabled. please check using `phpinfo()`.

**Reference Link**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821624/9533638

**OR**

you can use this one to convert png image to jpg. it will work.

=> https://github.com/free-open-source/php-image-converter/blob/master/src/ImageConverter.php